# success functions refresh div on parent page

Tags: jquery

I have parent.php which calls child.php through `$('#child').load('child.php?id='+id)`.
On the child.php page I have an onclick event which does some stuff (mysql etc..), with a success function.
Back on parent.php I also call anotherchild.php through a similar #div.load().

I would like the anotherchild.php to refresh within its div with the child.php success function.

Is this possible?

Comment: Simply load `anotherchild.php` again within the parent's success function?

Comment: the problem it that the success function is in child.php, the success function is a hide/show div, on child.php page.

Comment: can't your success function in child call a function (e.g. notifyParent) declared in the parent? In the end, all is HTML and javascript that ends up loaded in a same page...

Comment: Could do that I'll think about it thanks>>

Answer (score 0):

Any javascript you have in the child page is not evaluated as you are loading it through ajax and the result is not evaluated by the browser, it's just a string, unless jQuery has made some serious changes to their ajax code.

You would need to load the child.php in an iframe and then execute

```
parent.function();
```

Alternatively you could run a function when the ajax query finished, eg.

```
$('#child').load('child.php?id='+id, function() { console.log('Child Loaded'); });
```

Comment: the javascript on child page works fine, divs hide and show onclick event, when loaded through parent. What I need is the parent page to know that the onclick event in child.php has been successful to reload anotherchild: `$('#anotherchild').load('anotherchild.php?id='+id)`. Or something similar.